# retrieve only video length or duration (one by one) by providing video name with jplayer jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jplayer

i attached jplayer jquery,working well,
but in one page i want to list video name with video duration or length ,
so is it possible to create function ,
by using the function just pass only vidoe name it retrieve duration and length,
all videos are in one folder
I DONT WANT TO USE  ffmpeg and also getid3 ...thx in advance

Comment: What Code You've written? Show Us!

Comment: Jenson..  i had not implement any code....i retrieve all video name dynamicall but i cant found any source to get video duration